# MS-DOS Debug command what key is pressed

Tags: dos

Hello I'm trying to create a command/code on MS-DOS Debug to see what key I press on the keyboard. The code I have only works for one keypress but it doesn't work when I press different keys.

I want it to work with 2 or more different keys with individual output msgs depending on which key was pressed i.e hex 54 you pressed shift-F1

```
Mov ah, 0
Int 16
Mov bh, ah
Mov bl, al
Cmp ah, 3b
Jne again
Mov ah, 9
Mov dx, [msg address]
Int 21
Int 20
Db ‘You pressed F1 key$’
```

Answer (score -1):

If it is not crucial here, you can constantly read input from 0x60h port and see what it gives. Value below 128 is a key press, when above 127 is a key release. You don't use the interrupt then.

Try to take input from 0x60h port first in higher level language, I advise QBASIC. Then you will be able to quickly write a solution in asm.

Don't forget to make possibility to exit your program, for example by Esc key, which pressed gives value 1, or you will need to reboot your system to take control over system back.

Comment: Why minus? Please add comment why you not like the answer!